# Given the number of rectangles in a lattice, can the size of the lattice be determined?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To make things clear, let's define an $X\times Y$ lattice (where $X,Y\in\Bbb Z_+$) as the set
$$\{(j,k): 0\le j<X, 0\le k<Y, j,k\in\Bbb Z\}$$
And a rectangle in a such lattice is a rectangle whose vertices belong to this set. There are
$$\frac{X(X-1)Y(Y-1)}4$$
rectangles in the lattice.

Now the problem:

> Given the number of rectangles in an $X\times Y$ lattice, can the
>   product $XY$ be determined?

Or, in other words:

> Is the set $$\left\{\left(\frac{XY(X-1)(Y-1)}4,XY\right):X,Y\in\Bbb
>  Z_+\right\}$$ a function?

**My try**:

Let $P=XY$, and $S=X+Y$. Let be $N$ the number of rectangles. Then
$$P(P-S+1)=4N$$
That is,
$$P^2-(S-1)P-4N=0$$
so $(S-1)^2+16N$ is a perfect square.
But since $S$ and $P$ have some relation (namely, $S^2-4P$ must be also a perfect square), this does not seem a sufficient condition, and I honestly don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so.

A $4\times 4$ lattice and a $2 \times 9$ lattice both have $N=36$ rectangles, but the first has $XY = 16$ while the second has $XY=18$.

There are other counterexamples. A simple spreadsheet can produce such counterexamples immediately.